# Firebase realtime database write crash android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a simple code to write to firebase realtime database. However when activity that writes to database is opened it crashes the app. 
This is the code i'm using:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class main_view extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_view);

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("message");



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageValue = "Hello world";
                mRef.setValue(messageValue);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have no idea what goes wrong here

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @EraftYps In logcat `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

Comment: At which line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: `Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `findViewById()` in the on onCreate method after the layout has been inflated. You initialize the variable button outside onCreate before the layout has been inflated, therefore it is set to null.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageValue = "Hello world";
                mRef.setValue(messageValue);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Solves the previous error but opens a new one. `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp$IdTokenListener;` on line `final DatabaseReference mRef = database.getReference("message");`

Comment: It's related to the firebase dependencies in your app/build.gradle. Try looking for the error, there are already answers related to that.

Comment: I updated all the dependencies in my app/build.gradle and it worked. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

This line may create problem if you write it directly under the class. Place it inside onCreate().